# I am trying to view a data in my ejs view but it's throwing city is not defined

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is my codes I am getting errors not defined error

```
otat.get("/citySearch", async (req, res) => {
 var keywords = req.query.keyword;
 const response = await amadeus.referenceData.locations
  .get({
     keyword: keywords,
     subType: "CITY,AIRPORT",
}).then(function(response){
  res.render("flights", {city:response})
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

});

The view is

```
<%= city %>
```

Comment: before passing city variable, try `console.log(response)`

Comment: console.log(respose)
shows the data I want

Comment: `res.render("flights"` is the right file? probably the path is wrong